# Manually adding drag and drop support

Tags: apache-flex, drag-and-drop

I have a container that contains an image that I need to drag from one container to the other. The Flex language references don't specify anything useful, nor did I find a tutorial for how to do this. How do I manually add drag and drop support for elements like images?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you look at the drag and drop manager of Flex?

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/quickstart/adding_drag_and_drop/